# How to display the search result from array of object in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, html, rxjs

So I am using rxjs library and implementing my code using simple javascript. So I used ajax to make an API request for games and then mapped all the data inside the table, the table has the name of the game, released date, and genre. Now I have to only show the row based on the input search; basically, the user will search the game by name and only the data of that respective game will be shown in that particular row. How can we achieve such functionality using Rxjs?

I have added the snippet of the code.

Note: It takes 4-5 sec to fetch data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>>
</head>


<body>
   
    <h1>Games</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search_game" placeholder="search games">
    <p id="test"></p>
    <table cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;"id="game_name">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Released</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Genre</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody id="table-content">

        </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
const { of, fromEvent, ajax: { ajax }, operators: { startWith, switchMap, map, debounce }, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const searchGame = document.getElementById('search_game');


const search = fromEvent(searchGame, 'input');
search.subscribe(e=>console.log(e.target.value));
const games = ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games');
games.subscribe(gamesList => {
    let tableContent = '';
    gamesList.forEach(game => {
        tableContent += `<tr>`;
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
    })
    document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
    console.log(gamesList);
})
var x = document.getElementById('game_name').value;


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the search to it's value and make it start with something so you don't need to press a key first.

```
const search = fromEvent(searchGame, 'input').pipe(
  map(e => e.target.value),
  startWith('')
);
```

then you can use combine latest on the two observables to filter the games to just the ones where the name contains the search string.

```js
const { of, fromEvent, ajax: { ajax }, operators: { startWith, switchMap, map, debounce }, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const searchGame = document.getElementById('search_game');

const search = fromEvent(searchGame, 'input').pipe(
  map(e => e.target.value),
  startWith('') // Otherwise you wont get any results until you press a key
);

const games = ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games');

combineLatest([games, search]).pipe(
  map(([games, search]) => games.filter(game => game.name.indexOf(search) !== -1))
)
.subscribe(gamesList => {
    let tableContent = '';
    gamesList.forEach(game => {
        tableContent += `<tr>`;
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
    })
    document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        
<h1>Games</h1>
<input type="text" name="" id="search_game" placeholder="search games">
<p id="test"></p>
<table cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left;"id="game_name">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Released</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Genre</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody id="table-content">

    </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```